# How can I get OnCommand to detect DTN_DATETIMECHANGE?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, datetimepicker

My `CDialog` has two date time controls (one for a time and one for a date):

```
LTEXT           "Meeting Time:",IDC_STATIC,149,20,46,8
CONTROL         "",IDC_DTP_MEETING_TIME,"SysDateTimePick32",DTS_RIGHTALIGN | DTS_UPDOWN | WS_TABSTOP | 0x8,148,31,76,15
LTEXT           "Last Invited:",IDC_STATIC,149,49,42,8
CONTROL         "",IDC_DTP_LAST_INVITED,"SysDateTimePick32",DTS_RIGHTALIGN | WS_TABSTOP,147,60,100,15
```

I am trying to use `OnCommand` to detect when alot of the controls have been updated:

```
BOOL CCongregationDlg::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    const auto nMessage = HIWORD(wParam);
    const auto nControlID = LOWORD(wParam);

    if(IsWindowVisible())
    {
        if (nMessage == CBN_SELCHANGE ||
            nMessage == DTN_DATETIMECHANGE ||
            nMessage == EN_CHANGE)
        {
            IsModified(true);
            SetControlStates();

        }
        else if (nMessage == BN_CLICKED && nControlID == IDC_CHECK_LOCAL_CONGREGATION)
        {
            IsModified(true);
            SetControlStates();

        }
    }

    return __super::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

It works fine for the combos and the edit boxes but the `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` doesn't seem to be detected?

---

I found this conversation about [Notifications](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?135901-Notifications) where it states:

> I found out, that `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` works with `OnNotify`

I appreciate that I can add a handler for `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` to each control and track `IsModified` that way. But is it not possible to do something similar to what I am doing with `OnCommand`?

Comment: That's explicitly spelled out in the documentation for [`DTN_DATETIMECHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtn-datetimechange): *"This notification code is sent in the form of a `WM_NOTIFY` message."* In addition, the documentation for [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify) hints at why we arrived at a confusing situation: *"Some notifications, chiefly those that have been in the API for a long time, are sent as `WM_COMMAND` messages."* So, in essence, we have two distinct ways that controls use to send notifications.

Comment: Since you can simply add a  handler for `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` and this works, why ever get into all this? Because you want to have a single point where you handle those "change notifications", I guess? All you seem to do is the `IsModified()` and `SetControlStates()` calls. If it gets more complicated you can simply put these in a function and call this one instead. As for `OnCommand()`, if the `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` notification is NOT sent as a `WM_COMMAND` message, then it doesn't, period. Still, you can somehow "emulate" it, in the handler send a `WM_COMMAND` message to the dialog yourself.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou No need for emulation. I simply use `OnCommand` and `OnNotify``. And yes, it is to avoid adding x number of handlers to call the same code (even if one function) when I can do it in one handler. Less maintenance.

Comment: Yes, but if `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` isn't sent through a `WM_COMMAND` message it won't be processed by `OnCommand()`. Then you will have to process it in `OnNotify()`, checking the codes and IDs, as attempted in the 2nd post -btw I can't see why casts don't work, at least the `static_cast`, Win32 is C-based, and even a C-style cast (LPARAM to a pointer type) should work. The "emulation" I proposed is one single line of code (send a `WM_COMMAND` message so it can be processed as `EN_CHANGE` for example), and doesn't meddle with the higher-level logic of the "modified" state or your other controls.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Why bother emulating? The whole point is that I don't hand bespoke handlers in the dialog for the DTP to detect the date time changing. I got it sorted - simply - already. But thanks for suggestions. And thanks for comments re casting.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I needed `reinterpret_cast`. The build output was telling to do that - missied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from @Ilnspectable and furher research I came up with:

```
BOOL CCongregationDlg::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    const NMHDR* pNMHDR = reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(lParam);

    if (pNMHDR != nullptr)
    {
#pragma warning(suppress: 26454) 
        if (wParam == IDC_DTP_LAST_INVITED ||
            wParam == IDC_DTP_MEETING_TIME)
        {
            if (pNMHDR->code == DTN_DATETIMECHANGE)
            {
                IsModified(true);
                SetControlStates();

            }

        }
    }

    return __super::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);
}
```

---

Resources:

- [`CWnd::OnNotify`](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/bb87b9c66a2acaa6.htm)
- [`CWnd::OnNotify`](http://icodeguru.com/vc&mfc/mfcreference/html/_mfc_cwnd.3a3a.onnotify.htm)